# Kotlin lambdas and type inference

Tags: lambda, kotlin, type-inference, predicate

I implemented the following enum in Kotlin

```
enum class PlaylistAction(val playlistFilter:(Playlist) -> Boolean) {
    PLAY ({ it.playListOwner.Id == "xxx" }),
    SAVE({true})
}
```

I would like to use it to filter a List like this:

```
var test = playlists.filter { playlistActionType.playlistFilter}
```

where playlistActionType is of type `PlaylistAction` and playlists is `List<Playlist>`

**But** i am getting the following error:

> Error:(122, 34) Type mismatch: inferred type is (Playlist) -> (Playlist) -> Boolean but (Playlist) -> Boolean was expected

Why is the inferred type (Playlist) -> (Playlist) -> Boolean and not (Playlist) -> Boolean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By putting your predicate in `{}`, you are actually creating another lambda that returns your predicate as a result and this is why you end up with: `(Playlist) -> (Playlist) -> Boolean` instead of `(Playlist) -> Boolean`.

Using normal brackets should do the trick:

```
var test = playlists.filter(playlistActionType.playlistFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = playlists.filter(playlistActionType.playlistFilter)
```

will work. You're passing a function to `filter`, there is no need for an additional lambda.